# AngularJS $routeProvider can't specify groups of optional parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have an angular view that displays a list and an optional detail of an item with a compound primary key (because the list aggregates results from multiple databases).

When an item from the list is clicked I want the URL to change so that the individual items are bookmark-able, but I don't want the whole view to re-load because it would result in a costly re-query for all the items across multiple databases. It's easiest to demonstrate what I wished existed and hope that something like this *does* exist:

```
$routeProvider
  .when("/review/(databases/{dbid}/items/{id})?", {
      template: 'review.html',
      controller: 'ReviewCtrl',
  })
```

I've tried using a search string with `reloadOnSearch: false`, but that clears the search string when `/review?database=x&item=y` is navigated to.  I've thought about a hash, but my users are still on IE8 and are insistent that they'll be on 8 until mid-2015 when they finally upgrade past Windows XP, so I need the hash for routing...Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked into using ui.router at all? It's a more powerful alternative to ngRoute, and supports nested views (and therein nested linking). You could then have an item as a child state within your 'review' page, allowing you to navigate between child states without reloading the parent.

Comment: I'm a bit nervous about the "don't use in production" warning.  I suppose it's pretty popular though...